# Getting a PHP COM object of the active window

Tags: php, com

Is there a way to reference the active window using the PHP COM object?

I've never worked with it before, but am trying to use the imagegrabwindow() function and on the PHP site they demo it using:

```
$browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
```

Which generates a new IE window and I can get a screencap of that no problem.  But I'm working in Chrome and want the same result on the current window.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't realy an answer, but too long for a comment.

i think you missunderstood how that demo works (correct me if i'm wrong, please). this demo has nothing to do with the browser you're using to open you php site. the COM executes "InternetExplorer.Application" on the Server (so, IE hast to be installed there) and communicates with that, not with the clients one. this means (but i'm not sure) this should also be possible with any other program installed *on the server*.

Comment: I get that the demo is about opening a new window and has nothing to do with the current or active window, but that is what I'm trying to figure out.  How can I get a COM object referencing the current window?  PHP can take a screenshot of a COM object, but all the demo's I can find are about create a new browser window.  I want to see if it is possible to reference the current window rather than a new one.

Comment: you can't. php is executed on the server, you can't take a screenshot from the clients browser in that way. you'll need something executed on clients side to do this, but i'm realy not in expert in that... maybe flash can do it, i don't know.